# How to use a one sided test case to find which primer pairs are best?

Tags: r, self-study, anova, t-test, biostatistics

I am assessing which potential primer pairs are good among 6 primer pairs (pairs p1 to p6). The criterion is that a good primer pair should amplify DNA at minimum 1.95 times every cycle (1.95 fold amplification per cycle). [The data gives the DNA amount of the particular PCR cycle number (column) for each primer pair (row).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FHPD.jpg) You can click on the image to magnify it. Which primer pair(s) are good? – give a statistical argument. Use a 1-sided test case.

How would I go about approaching which primer pairs amplify the DNA 1.95 times per cycle with a one sided case? I am confused with regards to this? I originally thought I'd just use the slope, but I have a feeling I'm missing something here.

| Primer Pair | Cycle 1 DNA amount | Cycle 2 | Cycle 3 | Cycle 4 | Cycle 5 | Cycle 6 | Cycle 7 | Cycle 8 | Cycle 9 | Cycle 10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 3 | 7.7 | 17.7 | 39.2 | 80.7 | 143.0 | 317.7 | 640.1 | 1176.6 | 2322.2 |
| P2 | 6.5 | 6.7 | 16.3 | 32.8 | 69.1 | 116.1 | 245.6 | 448.1 | 923.3 | 1780.3 |
| P3 | 6.5 | 5.8 | 7.1 | 10.3 | 10.9 | 7.5 | 6.3 | 10.5 | 10.1 | 21.1 |
| P4 | 14.1 | 11.1 | 7.3 | 17.0 | 33.7 | 63.6 | 124.1 | 235.6 | 414.5 | 759.9 |
| P5 | 4.3 | 11.8 | 27.2 | 56.5 | 108.5 | 234.1 | 500.1 | 957.5 | 1892.3 | 3936.4 |

Answer (score 0):

You should be focused on a slope, as you think. The trick with PCR data in practice is that a reliable slope related to amplification efficiency doesn't typically extend over the entire range of PCR cycles. At low cycle numbers, the background signal (e.g., fluorescence) tends to overwhelm the DNA-associated signal. At high cycle numbers, reagents are often completely consumed so that there is no further increase in DNA-associated signal.

What's done in practice is to plot the data separately for each primer set, with `log2 DNA` on the vertical axis and cycle number on the horizontal axis. Identify visually the region on each curve where there is a linear association between log2 DNA and cycle number, then assess the slopes of those regions. Perfect amplification would have a slope of 1 on that scale. A one-sided test could then be a test of whether the slope is greater than what corresponds to a 1.95-fold amplification, or `log2(1.95)`.